# DatePickerDialog leaves white space android

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a date picker dialog ,[image: there is a white space as shown in image]

when ever dialog opens it shows the white space as shown in image(in right side of datePicker) ,

i tried setting layout Params

```
DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(_context, this,
                _birthYear, _month,
                _day);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        dialog.getDatePicker().setLayoutParams(params);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.getDatePicker().setSpinnersShown(false);
        dialog.getDatePicker().setCalendarViewShown(true);
```

still it aint working

any suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best way to fit this is to use scale in your code.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <DatePicker
                android:id="@+id/datePicker"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
                android:scaleX="1.2"
                android:scaleY="1.2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Try out this code I hope that will help you

Comment: white space removed, but it damaged the view, cannot use it thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: What issue you get share that issue

Comment: i have been calling DatePickerDialog from activity whose style sets minimum and max height and width to 90% , i tried using different style for date picker dialog : DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(_context, R.style.AppTheme_popDate ,this, _birthYear, _month, _day); still it didnt worked

Answer (score 0):

**Try to set the width to MATCH_PARENT over here.**

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
```

TO:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
```

**Updated ans:**

> There seems to be a size mismatch with the datepicker dialog and your
>   view.

**Try setting the size of the dialog like this:**

```
datepikerdialog.getWindow().setLayout(width,height)
```

Comment: Try to set the width and height of DAtepicker to wrapcontent. There seems to be an issue with your size. Check the updated ans pls.

Comment: ok i just found the problem , i have been calling DatePickerDialog from activity whose style sets minimum and  max height and width to 90% ,

i tried using different style for date picker dialog :
           DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(_context, R.style.AppTheme_popDate ,this,
                    _birthYear, _month,
                    _day); 

still it didnt worked